# Remote Assistance working but not Remote Desktop - both machines are XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have Remote Assistance working but not Remote Desktop.

XP Firewall has exceptions for both Remote Assistance and Remote Desktop.  Remote Desktop is allowed in System Properties - Remote.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check

- is the account having *administrator right*?
- is the account having a *password* set?

to further clarify your question,

- can you connect to the logon screen?
- what is the error message?

Comment: I don't even get a login screen. Just a message saying that the connections was disconnected.

Comment: Understood. Then check: (1) Can you ping the machine? (2) Can you connect to the port? (i.e. is the port in the remote computer open to you? use utilities such as nmap (google nmap).)

Here, (1) If you can connect to the port, but unable to connect --> protocol problem. - then check RDP version, client setting, server setting e.g. is there forced encryption? (2) If you can't even connect, check firewall(s) in between. some ISP blocks RDP.

Comment: remote assistance works between the 2 machines

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

- Verify that RDP is the same level on
  both machines.
- Set the display's Hardware
  acceleration to None.
- Update the display drivers to the
  latest versions (from the
  manufacturer's site).

Comment: What do you mean by "same level"?  I can get Remote Assistance working so the firewalls are not blocking that port.

Comment: @Craig Johnston: I mean that the RDP software is same version, although that's a somewhat long shot. As a remark: it wouldn't hurt to reinstall the RDP client, even if same version. I also erased the unsuitable port suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Remote Desktop is enabled (it's a separate checkbox from Remote Assistance) and make sure that your version of windows includes Remote desktop - Home version does *not*, but Professional does.

Comment: As stated in the question, both machines are XP Pro.